# Substrings not found when searching file created with echo command using C program

Tags: c, command, echo, getline, fread

I am working on a C program that is supposed to count the number of occurrences of a list of substrings in a given file. When I test the program with a file that I manually create and populate with text, it works fine and correctly counts the occurrences of each substring. However, when I try to use the program on a file created with the `echo` command, the program does not seem to be able to find any occurrences of the substrings, even though I can see that the substrings are present in the file when I open it with a text editor.

I have checked the program's logic and I believe it is correct, but I'm not sure why it's not working with the file created with `echo`.

Here's a simplified version of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
int num_substrings = 0;
int use_systemcall = 0; 

void search_file(char *filename, char *substring) {
    // Open the file with the given filename in read mode
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    
    // Check if the file was successfully opened
    if (file == NULL) {
        // Print an error message and exit the program with an error code
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not open file '%s'\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int count = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *line;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    
    // Read the file line by line until the end
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
        // Skip the last line if it is empty
        if (read == 1 && line[0] == '\n') {
            continue;
        }

        // Strip any newline characters from the end of the line
        if (line[read - 1] == '\n') {
            line[read - 1] = '\0';
            read--;
        }
    
        // Find the first occurrence of the given substring in the current line
        char *match = strstr(line, substring);
    
        // While there are still occurrences of the substring in the current line
        while (match != NULL) {
            // Increment the counter and find the next occurrence of the substring
            count++;
            match = strstr(match + 1, substring);
        }
    }
    
    // Close the file
    fclose(file);
    
    // Print the number of occurrences of the substring found in the file
    printf("Found %d occurrences of substring '%s' in file '%s'\n",
           count, substring, filename);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Get the filename from the first command-line argument
    char *filename = argv[1];
    
    // Initialize an array to store the substrings and a counter for the number of substrings
    char substrings[10][100];
    int num_substrings = 0;
    
    // Loop through the remaining command-line arguments (starting from the second one)
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        // Copy the current argument (substring) into the substrings array
        strcpy(substrings[num_substrings], argv[i]);
        
        // Increment the counter for the number of substrings
        num_substrings++;
    }
    
    // Ask the user if they want to use a system call
    printf("Do you want to use system call? (y/n): ");

    char answer[10];
    fgets(answer, 10, stdin);
    
    // Check if the user answered yes (y or Y) and set the use_systemcall variable accordingly
    int use_systemcall = 0;
    if (answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'Y') {
        use_systemcall = 1;
    }

    printf("Filename: %s\n", filename);
    printf("Substrings: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_substrings; i++) {
        printf("%s ", substrings[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    // Open the file for reading
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Cannot open file %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Initialize a buffer to read the file in blocks of 100 characters
    char buffer[101];
    
    // Loop through each substring and search for it in the file
    for (int i = 0; i < num_substrings; i++) {
        // Reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        
        // Initialize a counter for the number of occurrences of the substring
        int count = 0;
        
        // Loop through the file in blocks of 100 characters
        while (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 100, file) > 0) {
            // Add a null terminator at the end of the buffer
            buffer[100] = '\0';
            
            // Search for the substring in the buffer
            char *result = strstr(buffer, substrings[i]);
            
            // If the substring is found, increment the count
            while (result != NULL) {
                count++;
                
                // Move the result pointer to the next character after the match
                result++;
                
                // Search for the substring again starting from the result pointer
                result = strstr(result, substrings[i]);
            }
        }
        
        // Print the number of occurrences of the substring
        printf("'%s' appears %d times in the file.\n", substrings[i], count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Command:

```
echo "hello world" > foo.txt    ---For creating file
./substring_search foo.txt world -- for searching substrings
```

output:

```
'world' appears 0 times in the file.
```

Can anyone help me figure out what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it?

Comment: Since you're reading the file in 100 byte chunks, you won't match any words that are split across chunks. But that shouldn't be a problem for this small file.

Answer (score 2):

Code has some troubles:

**Incomplete block read**

It file was say 50 bytes, then `buffer[100] = '\0'` does not make `buffer[]` the correct *string*.  Better to use the length returned from `fread()`.  I suspect this is OP's key issue.

**Substring crosses block boundary**

`strstr(buffer, substrings[i]);` does not detect a substring if part of it is in one block and the remainder in another.

**Out of range access**

```
char substrings[10][100];
```

`substrings[num_substrings]` is bad when `num_substrings >= 10`.

`strcpy(substrings[num_substrings], argv[i]);` is bad when the source string's length is 100 or more.

***Null character* in the file?**

`strstr(buffer, substrings[i])` will stop early than reading the whole `buffer[]` should the source file contain a `'\0'`.

**Check `argc` first**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Insufficient arguments\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  
  // OK now to save the argument for later fopen() use. 
  char* filename = argv[1];
  ... 
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
```

**`"\n"` vs. `"\r\n"`**

Should the manually created file or the *echo* file have different line endings, I do not see this should make a difference for OP - yet be aware of this in debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The *simplified* version of the program does not produce the posted output: there is no question about system calls and the filename output is missing. I get this output for the **foo.txt** file created with `echo`:

```
Do you want to use system call? (y/n): y
Filename: foo.txt
Substrings: world
'world' appears 1 times in the file.
```

The program has some problems but none that should prevent the expected output:

- no sanity tests on the number of command line arguments or the length of individual strings.
- unused global variables that are shadowed by local variables with the same name
- unused function `search_file` that uses a different method to read the file and should also produce the expected output.
- the `main` function reads the file 100 bytes at a time, so matches that overlap block boundaries will not be counted
- partial reads will not be null terminated at the end of the partial read, causing matches that occur at the end of the previous block to be counted twice.

You should simplify the posted code and ensure it still has the problem.